# Android OpenGL engine - Rajawali

Tags: android, opengl-es, rajawali

I have downloaded Rajawali project. In it manifest is defined that it runs on API15 and newer, but when I try to build my project (Rajawali is added as support library) I saw that Rajawali need android.server.dreams, which is part of API 17.

So where is my mistake ?

P.S. I have checked my API to 17 just to check if it will works. But...it doesn't, still can't find package.